# Loading and georeferencing historic maps using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, historical-maps

I have recently started working with QGIS.

I am unsure of how to go about inserting historical maps which have no referencing data.

I think it might be possible to insert them, then move and scale them using a modern mapping layer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

It is Georeferencing that I would use to try and do this.

I have done that for Australian maps from the 19th century related to family history.

As [commented by @user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159994/how-to-load-and-reference-historic-mapping#comment237062_159994) there is a [Georeferencer Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html) for QGIS.

If you try, and get stuck, then just ask a more focussed question about precisely where you get stuck.